# cannot commit with autocommit set

Tags: mysql, jboss

Hi
   I got the following error when I deploy my application on `jboss`. I have use

> "session.connection().commit();" (The
>   method connection() from the type
>   Session is deprecated) in my code.
>
> Error : You cannot commit with
>   autocommit set! 16:31:19,223 ERROR
>   [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: You
>   cannot commit with autocommit set!
>   16:31:19,223 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:645)

my DS:

```
<xa-datasource> 
<jndi-name>jbpmDS</jndi-name> 
<xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class > 
<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.51:3306/jbpm4</xa-datasource-property> 
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
<connection-property name="autoCommit">false</connection-property>
<user-name>root</user-name> 
<password>password</password> 
<transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation> 
<max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size> 
<min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size> 
<blocking-timeout-millis>2000</blocking-timeout-millis> 
<idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes> 
<track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>
<new-connection-sql>set autocommit=0</new-connection-sql>
<no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name> 
<metadata> 
    <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping> 
</metadata> 
</xa-datasource>
```

Can any One tell me why I got this error? and how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XA datasource can only commit/rollback over transaction. The commit/rollback over connection will not work.

Try this in your code.

```
tx=session.beginTransaction()
```

Business Logic

```
tx.commit()
```